# Angular - Asynchronous operation with request interceptor

Tags: angularjs, angular-http-interceptors

I have my request interceptor like below :

```
var requestFactory = angular.module('queryParamsModule', [])
        .factory('headerInterceptor', function($injector) {

          return {
            request: requestInterceptor
          };

          function requestInterceptor(req) {
              var accessToken;
              $injector.get('tokenService').accessToken().then(function(res) {
                accessToken = res.access_token;
                console.log(accessToken);  >>>>> accessToken is populated fine!
                req.headers = _.extend({
                  'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + accessToken
                }, req.headers);
              }, function(e) {
                // error
              });

            return req;
          }

        })
        .config(function($httpProvider) {
          $httpProvider.interceptors.push('headerInterceptor');
        });

      return queryParamsFactory;
```

The issue here is, angular doesnt wait for the Authorization Header to be added in request and pushes the interceptor before adding Authorization header.

Is there a way I can make my header interceptor part of the promise which is resolved after accessToken promise is complete?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors) says,

> request: interceptors get called with a http config object. The function is free to modify the config object or create a new one. The function needs to return the config object directly, or a promise containing the config or a new config object.

So it should be:

```
  function requestInterceptor(req) {
      return $injector.get('tokenService').accessToken().then(function(res) {
        ...
        return req;
      }, function(e) { ... });
  }
```

Comment: Worked like charm. Thanks much!